# Check if a variable that can be either duration or timedelta is larger than 0?

Tags: python, isodate

I am using isodate to parse durations in isoformat to dates:

```
>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1M")
isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=0, months=1)

>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1D")
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Months are parsed into `duration` objects and days are parsed into `timedelta` objects, as described in the docs: https://pypi.org/project/isodate/

I want to test if the value of a variable that can be of either `duration` type or `timedelta` type is larger than 0. The method that works for the `duration` type does not work for the `timedelta` type and vice versa.

```
>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1M") > 0
True

>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1D") > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to int



>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1M") > timedelta.min
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to Duration

>>> isodate.parse_duration("P1D") > timedelta.min
True
```

What is a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if variable instance is datetime.timedalta or Duration:

```
def is_larger_than_0(duration):
    if isinstance(duration, datetime.timedelta):
        if duration > datetime.timedelta.min:
            return True
    elif isinstance(duration, Duration):
        if duration > 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function than applies the appropriate method for each type:

```
def is_greater_than_zero(duration):
  if type(duration) is isodate.duration.Duration:
    return duration > 0
  elif type(duration) = 'datetime.timedelta':
    return duration > timedelta.min

is_greater_than_zero(duration)
```